# How to access ListView subitem by Key?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview

I am trying to access data from list view using columnheader name but I get errors

```
LVProduct.FocusedItem.SubItems("Name").Text
```

So, how do you use the function with string parameters? I don't want to use index it is too confusing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create the sub items, you have to set the Name property to be that of the column in which it resides.

The [...] accessor looks up the Name field in the ListViewSubItem class.

Without that set, the ["Name"].text operation you're carrying out will return a null pointer type error.

Or, to put it another way, the search by key does not search by column name.
It searches according to the value that you set in SubItem.Name when you create the subitem.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b96f9fbe-e128-4b49-833d-2a5f6e678dae/access-listview-subitem-text-by-column-header?forum=winforms

Comment: Weird... i'm getting an empty string when i messagebox the .Name of the SubItems or ColumnHeaders.

Answer (score 14):

If you're wanting to get the SubItem based on a column, this is the easiest way.

```
LVProduct.FocusedItem.SubItems(columnHeader1.Index).Text
```

columnHeader1 would be the name of the ColumnHeader you're wanting the SubItem from.

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately I can't give more than one upvote.

Answer (score 5):

When creating the sub items you need to set the name property. For example:

```
listViewItem.SubItems.Add(
    New ListViewSubItem With {.Name = "Name", .Text = "yes"}
)
```

Then you can use your existing code:

```
LVProduct.FocusedItem.SubItems("Name").Text
```

Answer (score -1):

Your supposed to use c# "indexer" . You have to call using sqare brackets:

```
LVProduct.FocusedItem.SubItems["Name"].Text
```

If you want to know more on indexer, look at [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)